# Segmentation fault for git commit command (Windows)

Tags: windows, git, commit, fault

I have started to work with project, which I cloned from bitbucket. 
I use as Git Bash, as SourceTree.
I changed one file and try to commit my change.
I can execute the command "add", but when I try to execute the command "commit" (git commit -m "for testing"), I get the following error:
Segmentation fault.

I got an error in SourceTree too.
But if I create my new folder & file, the commit happens successfully

How I can fix the problem situation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of git do you use? What is the exact output of the console. The first thing I see is surely to get the last version of git...

Comment: I used version 2.13.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved the problem.
The last git version (2.13.1) has the bug - it has been released 05.06.2017.
I installed previous version (2.12.2) and now all is OK.

Answer (score 13):

Running git 2.15.1.windows.2 on Windows 10 x64 v1709

For me the problem was caused by a faulty index. To resolve I ran the following from the project directory:

`rm .git/index`

`git reset`

[As you can see from the image in this link, I didn't loose any changes by performing a reset.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kINfQ.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

If you already have Git installed, you can get the latest development version via Git itself:

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git
```

but this didn't work for me.I uninstalled the git and then again downloaded then my problem got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on some project, I could no checkout a new or an existing branch.
I installed the latest version of git from the website and now my version is

```
> git --version
  git version 2.13.1.windows.2
```

The issue seems fixed with this build. For now.

Answer (score 0):

use `git reset SHA --hard`

Where `SHA` points to a valid SHA before the error

Changes done after this point is lost. But repo is saved.

Answer (score 0):

> For me the problem was caused by a faulty index.

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), you will see more details instead of a segfault.
Git now check the return value from `parse_tree_indirect()` to turn segfaults into calls to `die()`.
For `clone`/`checkout`, but can also be applied to `commit`.

See [commit 8d2eaf6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d2eaf649abd28baa083a723d1e041b26d2be83e) (01 Mar 2022) by [Glen Choo (`chooglen`)](https://github.com/chooglen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bde1e3e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bde1e3e80a16a850da95af836ef85c5669c989a2), 13 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`checkout, clone`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8d2eaf649abd28baa083a723d1e041b26d2be83e): die if tree cannot be parsed
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Glen Choo</sup>

> When a tree oid is invalid, `parse_tree_indirect()` can return `NULL`.
> Check for `NULL` instead of proceeding as though it were a valid pointer and segfaulting.